# Dynamic binding Listbox - Multiple Selection in Javascript

Tags: asp.net

I have two listboxes, One binds on pageload() and the other binds on button click event.
i have used Javascript for dynamic binding of listboxes on Button click.
On checking a Checkbox, i have to select multiple items that is selected in listbox (pageload()) to the listbox generated on button click.

My Javascript:

```
function bindingListBox()
{

   var optioncontent = document.getElementById(optionid);

   var lstdata = $("input[id$='hidSelectedItem']").val();

   var eachlstdata = lstdata.split("!@#$");

   for (var j = 0; j < eachlstdata.length; j++)

   {

      var separateeachlstvalue = eachlstdata[j].split(",");

      if(separateeachlstvalue != "")

      {

         optioncontent.value = separateeachlstvalue[0];

         optioncontent.text = separateeachlstvalue[1];

         optioncontent.setAttribute("selected","selected"); 

      } 

   }

}
```

"hidSelectedItem" - hiddenfield contains selected items in first listbox on checkbox check.

The above code selects only the last item on checkbox check.

Can you please help me to populate all the selected items in the ListBox created on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this

```
$("#lstbx1 option:selected").remove().appendTo("#lstbx2");
```